# Ошибка 404 при переносе сайта wordpress с локального сервера на хостинг

Tags: wordpress

всё в точности делал по инстукции
https://wp-lessons.com/kak-perenesti-sayt-wordpress-na-hosting

и при переходе по страницам - ошибка 404

Comment: По моему - тебе всё таки стоит прочитать документацию по WP, если ты пытаешься с ним работать, а не задавать тут бессмысленные вопросы по каждому шагу

Comment: @РашенБеар Не исключено)

Comment: Скачай БД в SQL, открой в редакторе и замени все localhost на  свой домен, сохрани, и загрузи БД обратно.

Comment: @Даниил да сколько ж можно! Ну прямой путь к разрушению базы

Comment: http://dimox.name/moving-the-site-on-new-domain/

Comment: Вот это надо читать, а не дурацкие инструкции на wp-lessons https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562/220220

Comment: @KAGGDesign мне норм. Все сайты так делал и делаю. Работает без проблем.

Comment: @Даниил это вы с современными темами и плагинами не работали

Comment: @РашенБеар еще один плохой совет

Comment: плагин WP Migrate DB  тоже самое делает ток в админки

Comment: @KAGGDesign чем отличаются современные плагины и темы от несовременных ?  Как узнать какая из них какая ? И как замена URL в БД может повлиять на работу плагина?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73032/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-).

Comment: @РашенБеар тому мануалу Дим-ка более 10лет. С тех пор ВП шел вперёд так же далеко, как  современные автомобили ушли от [телеги Кюньо](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D1%8E%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE)